# google Auth API (Google Drive API)

Tags: python, google-drive-api, telegram-bot

I have part of code that responsible for refreshing token. Bot it doesn't work. Because of that i need to rerun telegram-bot on server after changing token by myself. How can i makeit work?

here code:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

creds = None
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('client_secret_creds.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```

I tried to look in google for solution, but i still can't fix it.